# Facebook Connection not initiating

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to establish a simple connection to Facebook using the SDK provided on the Developer-page. However, the "window.fbAsyncInit"-function is never called, so the Console isn't displaying the "hello"-String. When I'm using a synchronous call, I'm getting an error saying "FB is not defined".

My Code (I replaced '[MY APP ID]' with the ID of my Facebook-App):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    console.log("hello");
    FB.init({
        appId      : '[MY APP ID]',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
<div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing anything important here?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you please provide a link so we can see the page live and check the javascript console?

Comment: I am currently working on a local page. No Errors there, the fbAsyncInit is just never called.

Answer (score 0):

By chance, are you testing by opening an html file on your local computer (e.g., *File > Open*)?

Protocol-relative paths (`//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`) don't work when you're viewing a local file, because the path it loads will be relative to your local drive (`file://///connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`)

Try adding an explicit `https:` to the the front of the two js paths and see if that helps!